# Add column and set default to value in other field

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in my database that needs to be restructured. It currently looks like this:

```
id  |              attrs  
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"type": "test_type", "m_attrs": {"left_values": "Jack", "right_values": "John"}}
```

However I am wanting to alter this table and split the `attrs` column into separate columns for `type`, `left_values` and `right_values`:

```
alter table t_name add column if not exists type text;
alter table t_name add column if not exists left_values text;
alter table t_name add column if not exists right_values text;
```

What is the best way to make these columns not null and have their default value set to the value in the existing attrs column, ie:
`attrs->m_attrs->>'left_value'`

The table is very large in terms of rows so I'm wary of performance issues too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PostgreSQL v12 on, it would be best to use *generated columns*:

```
ALTER TABLE t_name
   ADD "type" text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (attrs->>'type') STORED,
   ADD left_values text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (attrs->'m_attrs'->>'left_values') STORED,
   ADD right_values text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (attrs->'m_attrs'->>'right_values') STORED;
```

This will require a table rewrite, so it will take some time and space, but there is no way to avoid a table rewrite with an operation like that anyway. You can reduce the impact by doing it in a single `ALTER TABLE` as above.

For older database versions, you have to do it in steps:

- start a transaction so that the next steps blocks access to the table
- add (nullable) columns
- fill the columns with a single `UPDATE`
- turn the columns `NOT NULL` if desired
- create a trigger that fills the new columns automatically
- commit the transaction

Apart from providing atomicity, the transaction makes sure that no new rows are added before the trigger is in place.

After that, it might be good to `VACUUM (FILL)` the table (still more down time) to get rid of the bloat from the `UPDATE`.